# iPhone's class equivalent in Mac

Tags: iphone, macos

I have to migrate a iPhone application to Mac OSx.
Anybody knows where I can find a equivalence between the iPhone class (lets say UITableViewController) and the Mac equivalent?

Tankes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same language, different SDK. All the UI classes are different, though Foundation is mostly the same.

There is no equivalent to `UITableViewController`, for instance, as there is no `UITableView`, and `NSTableView` works very differently.

[Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/designing-view-with-bindings.html) has some useful info on making something similar on the Mac.

Comment: Tankes for the answer and the link.